# How do I export the pgAdmin Messages to a file simultaneously as the queries are running?

Tags: postgresql, logging, pgadmin

I am running queries that consume huge mount of time.

To track the progress, I raise messages at some key processes, which are displayed in Messages panel (as the image below shows).

In case of likely loss of the messages (happened before) due to power-off or Windows Update Restart (though I closed it) of my PC, is it feasible to **export the pgAdmin Messages to a file** simultaneously as query is running?

[image]

Comment: You could to set the [`log_min_messages` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-MESSAGES) to the `info` value to write messages to the server log: `alter system set log_min_messages to info;`

Comment: @Abelisto after I ran `alter system set log_min_messages to info;` and the `SHOW log_min_messages;` was still `warning`.

Comment: You need to reload server configuration or restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Abelisto a service restart works, cool! thx. So is this setting once and for all?

Comment: Yes. Generally it is possible to set parameters for system/database/role/session.

Comment: @Abelisto got it. and do you have any idea to kill the annoying 'CONTEXT:' line in the notice, such as `INFO:  
[2017-07-28 00:36:02] Funtion AC_QueryTripTraj is processing tables
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ac_querytriptraj(text,integer,integer,double precision,text,text,double precision) line 31 at RAISE`, and let notice be notice. I tried `alter system set log_error_verbosity=DEFAULT` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure that it possible. Instead you could to [configure logging into CSV format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and read only those fields that you want.